# How does .tk domain redirect to my ip(wordpress blog)?

Tags: php, wordpress, dns

I registered a .tk domain and redirect it to my server where my wordpress blog is installed. When I enter the domain it can go to my blog, but I find I can't login. When I use ip as my web address, I logged in successfully. I guess the redirection can only help me go to the index but in wordpress program they use inner links. So how to solve the problem?

Comment: there might be many reasons, if its not wordpress related, and you purchased domain just now its probably DNS propagation issue. If you can successfully ping your domain and all, you need to check logs whats going on.

Comment: @MuhammedM. Well,I tried to ping, I succeed when I use ip of my server but failed when I use the .tk domain.Any idea?

Comment: You can't ping domain name? DNS propagation might be the issue, when did you buy this domain? try on another computer. Try pinging online, like http://ping.eu/ping/

Comment: @MuhammedM. It's a free domain and I buy it today.I tried in an other computer,same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you bought your domain today, its probably DNS propagation issue. And you are saying you can ping IP but not domain from your computer, it confirms that. Try pinging online, like ping.eu/ping see if it shows up, until then patience.

Comment: Thanks,but I don't know why I type the domain name in my browser and can reach my server but failed to ping?

Comment: wait for dns to propagate, clear your browser cache, do ipconfig/flushdns and others, restart pc, if it is all the same, wait a few hours for dns to fully work. Most domain registrars say wait 24/48 hours.

Comment: Yes, it recovered this afternoon.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to log into WordPress using your .tk domain, you need to point your .tk domain to your nameservers instead of redirecting the domain.  To do the following...

1. Go to www.dot.tk and login
2. Navigate to Domains > My Domains > Manage Domain > Management Tools > Nameservers and update your nameservers.
3. Log into your WordPress site and go to Settings > General then change both the `WordPress Address (URL)` and `Site Address (URL)` to: yourdomain.tk instead of your IP address. You should the be able to log in normally using your .tk domain.

If you've found it helpful please mark this as the accepted answer to your question. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks,but when I change the Wordpress Address and Site Address, I find I can't even visit my blog.

Comment: This has happened to me before. Delete the domain and register it but this time choose to use your own dns during the registration instead of redirecting. Then, perform step #2 above. For some reason even though you are asked to enter your namservers during the registration you still need to perform this step again after the fact. Dot.tk is buggy that way but this is how I do it all the time and it works.  There usually isn't any propagation time delay either so you should be able to ping as well as visit your website immediately after you have finished the registration and step #2.